# What's a good cacheKey for react-select's NonceProvider

Tags: react-select, emotion

The [react-select 4.0 release notes](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/releases/tag/react-select%404.0.0) say that NonceProvider now needs a cacheKey, but it's not obvious what that cache key should be. Can I use the same cacheKey across my entire codebase? One per page? One per component?

Answer (score 0):

Unless they share the same styles you should use a different key per component.